# Closed form for this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a closed form for this series?

$\sum_{n=m}^Q n^n\cos(nx) $

I know that $\sum_{n=m}^Q n^n $ does not but does the cosine plays any role in this?

Comment: If a closed form for $\sum n^n \cos(nx)$ existed, setting $x=0$ in that formula would give a closed form for $\sum n^n$.

Comment: Ok, so obvious but couldn't see it! Thanks!